# Intel realsense SR300 and opencv is it broken?

Tags: opencv, realsense, perceptual-sdk

I have the Intel Perceptual Computing SDK installed and built opencv 3.3.0 with WITH_INTELPERC and also the Examples. I confirmed in CMake that Inter Perc was YES.

However when I go to run cpp-example-intelperc_capture.exe I get the error "Can not open a capture object".

The SR300 camera is working fine on this computer using the RealSense vewier. Is this feature broken in opencv or is there something I am missing?

Comment: Maybe try to open an issue [here](https://github.com/IntelRealSense/librealsense/issues)?

Comment: It is ok I decided to directly integrate using the SDK https://github.com/IntelRealSense/librealsense

Answer (score 0):

I am not very sure about your question, the LibRS 2.0 has the openCV wrapper inside and when you build the LibRS2.0, CMake will ask your openCV root directory. Your way seems like compile openCV with LibRS as part of the library, I don't think it is the right way.
For more detailed information and how to build the LibRS with openCV, please refer to link https://github.com/IntelRealSense/librealsense/tree/master/wrappers/opencv